# What is the Arabic word for "Demon" and "Angel"?

Tags: arabic, language, arabic-translation

*My teacher asked me those words, but unfortunately, I was not able to answer it because I don't know that words in Arabic language.*

Comment: Questions regarding the Arabic language itself, except how they're clearly relevant to the study of Islam, are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Demon in Arabic: شيطان
2. Angel in Arabic: ملاك

Comment: ملاك is not correct the correct word is ملك without alif!